# System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am using check box property as ischecked, but while debugging , the property is getting System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean], how to convert this to boolean value.

Please help me anyone. Thanks.

Comment: CheckBox control doesn't has an IsChecked property. Perhaps you mean Checked property...but still, show us some code so we can help you.

Comment: Yes, Iam getting like this System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]

Answer (score 0):

`CheckBox.IsChecked` is of type `Nullable(Of Boolean)` and [`Nullable(Of T)`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fb3h38hb0(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=B3TsU92RCKey0QXwmIDoCA&usg=AFQjCNE-wNQmDshGRhWCp1j9rTo62u1Z3Q&sig2=5Y3IUCa45YsW2lSCFbM8UQ&bvm=bv.72938740,d.d2k) generic class has a property named `Value` which returns a `T`.

So you can first check the value of `checkbox1.IsChecked.HasValue`. If it equals to False, then the checkbox is gray or Indeterminate. If it's True, the value in `checkbox1.IsChecked.Value` will determine if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
If checkbox1.IsChecked.HasValue Then
    If checkbox1.IsChecked.Value Then
        ' Checked 
    Else
        ' Unchecked
    End If
Else
    ' Indeterminate
End If
```

If you set the value of `CheckBox.IsThreeState` to false, you can always be sure that the value of `IsChecked` is true or false.

Comment: Which VS you are using? Because in VS 2013 there is no IsChecked property to CheckBox control...o.O

Comment: @Eminem This is not windows forms, it is WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx